# WPF Press any button to continue to next page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

Got a simple 3 page program, but would like to make a welcome screen that users have to press a button to move to the next page (and start the workflow).
Users will mostly be using a barcode scanner (captures string & hits enter), so I'm trying to avoid buttons that need to be clicked with a mouse.
The setup is basically one MainWindow with a DockPanel in it with a Frame in it. 
Pages get loaded to the frame on events(the enter being hit on a textbox). Pages have Grids in them with the standard controls.
I've got the frame in the window navigating to the welcome page, but can't seem to capture a keypress.
What would set I the event on? The Window, the frame, the dockpanel, the page, the grid?
Also, is there a way to specify "any key or click" event, maybe listen for any input action?
I've tried experimenting and looking at documentation but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: I don't believe there is a keypress event for for TextBox in WPF.  Also, a bar code scanner is equivalent to a keyboard to the application so any code scanned will appear as keyboard input to the WPF TextBox.  Also barcode scanners can be programmed to Send OR Not Send a carriage return so this is a bit difficult to answer unless you provide a little of the code you have and describe with greater clarity how you want it to react the given input.

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty WPF app with a frame and was able to catch a keypress event. Once the app starts I focus the frame. You can do the same once your page loads or when your workflow starts over.

```
<Frame Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded" KeyUp="UIElement_OnKeyUp">
    <Frame.Content>
        <Page>
            <Label Content="Hello"></Label>
        </Page>
    </Frame.Content>
</Frame>

private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Frame)sender).Focus();
}

private void UIElement_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Key pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your designer:

```
this.myForm.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.myForm_KeyDown);
```

---

And add this to your Form's code

```
private void myForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if(KeysDown().Any()) 
     {
         currentForm.Hide();
         nextForm,Show();
     }
}
```